# Inverse elements in Banach Algebra completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, functional-analysis, banach-algebras

currently I am starting my studies on Banach Algebra's and I have a question regarding the completion. Generally suppose that $A$ is an Algebra over $\mathbb C$ then one can create a **unital** Algebra by taking $\tilde{A} = A \times \mathbb{C}$ (We denote this by the **unitisation** of $A$), where multiplication is given by

$$
(a,\alpha)(b,\beta) = (ab+\alpha b + \beta a, \alpha \beta)
$$

One can prove that

1. $\tilde{A}$ is unital (Take $e_{\tilde{A}}=(0_A,1)$).
2. $\tilde{A}$ is commutative iff A is commutative. Moreover if $A$ admits a Banach space structure then one can turn $\mathcal{A} = A \times C$ together with the above multiplication into a unital Banach Algebra by setting the norm $\|(a,\lambda)\|_{\mathcal{A}} = \|a\|_A+|\lambda|_{\mathbb C}$. Lastly the mapping $(a,\lambda) \mapsto (a,0)$ gives an isometry between both spaces.

For me the following question remains:

1. Is it possible that an element in $a \in \tilde{A}$ is invertible?

What I have tried so far:

1. For the first one, I believe that **without** more algebraic structure on $A$ the only element is invertible is the unit in $\tilde{A}=A \times \mathbb{C}$.

Take any $(a,\alpha) \in \tilde{A}$ that is invertible, we want to prove that it is actually the unit. Using the definition inverse element there exists a $(b,\beta) \in A \times \mathbb{C}$ such that
$$
(ab+\alpha b + \beta a, \alpha \beta) \stackrel{!}{=} (0_A,1)
$$
This directly gives that $\alpha \neq 0$ and $\beta = \frac{1}{\alpha}$, thus we are left with
$$
ab + \alpha b + \alpha^{-1} a \stackrel{!}{=} 0_A
$$
However here I am stuck, since $b$ does not have to be the inverse in $A$.

I don't see a way to built a contradiction to this? Any hints are welcomed.

Comment: In 2) you maybe you meant: $\tilde A$ is commutative iff $A$ is commutative? also non-zero multiples of the unit are invertible as well.

Comment: Could you please edit & work over your post? It lacks precision & misnomers:
What you denote as completion (in the third line) is actually known as the unitisation.
Algebraically, this works as you indicated, and it yields a Banach algebra if the input is a Banach algebra. Point 2 is wrong as it stands. Correct is that $A$ is commutative if and only if $\tilde A$ is commutative.

Comment: It may help to consider concrete examples, e.g., the continuous complex-valued functions on the unit intervall $[0,1]$, vanishing at zero, and equipped with the supremum or maximum-norm. The unitisation of this Banach algebra (even a $C^*$-algebra) is the Banach algebra of all cont. functions on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Yes both of you are right regarding point 2 and other mistakes and I edited my post, hoping to make matters more clear.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a$ be such that $a^2=0$.
Then $(a,\alpha)$ has the inverse $(-\alpha^{-2}a, \alpha^{-1})$,
as
$$
a\cdot (-\alpha^{-2}a) + \alpha (-\alpha^{-2}a) + \alpha^{-1} a=0
$$
is satisfied. A similar construction can be done if $a^d=0$ for some $d>2$, then $b$ has to be a certain polynomial in $a$.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, the example makes sense. In your example you gave a self-invertible element in $A$ that gives rise to an element that is invertible in $\mathcal{A}$. Generally speaking, does an invertible element in $A$ give rise to an invertible element in $\mathcal{A}$? Can one even gain **additional invertible elements** in $\mathcal{A}$, which first coordinate are not invertible in $A$? (Or Vice-Versa?). With assumption that one has invertible element $b$ in $A$, I only found that must be of the form $$b=-\alpha^{-1}a(a+\mathbb{1}_A \alpha)^{-1}$$, which looks not promising.

Comment: I do not understand your comment. $a$ is not self-invertible, it is nilpotent.